# IIS Basics: How to change default site to remove welcome screen

Tags: iis, server

We are currently using an internal farm of two web servers running IIS on MS2019. In IIS, we have a site called `ABC` under the `Default Web Site`.

This farm is load balanced. When you go to the VIP (mysite.com), which sends the traffic to the appropriate web server, it goes directly to the IIS landing/welcome page. How can I configure IIS to redirect to s specific site versus the welcome page?

mysite.com --> mysite.com/ABC

Comment: Please hire someone to give your team some basic lessons of how IIS works. You cannot call `ABC` a site, because IIS concepts do not work that way, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis Once you know the needed, you will see how easy it is to get rid of the default web site and publish yours.

Comment: This link should help you: [Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing).